# How do I make a clip extension using an image texture node in Blender render?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, uv-image-editor

I'm not sure how I can clearly explain this as a noob, but how do I make an image node in texture editor not repeat its texture when it is outside of the UV map. The first image below is what I want it to look like, the bottom is what happens when I use the node editor.

[image: This is what I want it to look. Note that the texture doesn't repeat when it goes outside of the UV map]

[image: This is what happens when I use the node editor for the texture.]

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down your material panel to **Image Mapping** and change **Extension** from **Repeat** to **Clip**

[image]

Comment: Those controls are entirely absent when I use nodes for the texture.

Comment: If all you have is an image going to an output, i would just uncheck the Use Nodes, as it's not needed unless you are going to add more nodes later

Comment: Or add more space around your image in an image editor so it won't repeat as frequently